# Multiple Columns in Dynamic Sql Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

When i do this

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(50)
set @cmd ='SELECT category_id FROM tbl_BHMCategoryMaster '
exec(@cmd)
```

query executes properly.

But When I do this

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(50)
set @cmd ='SELECT [category_id],[category_name],[Basic],[Dimension],[In_Out],[ProfileHand],[Glass],[Hinge],[Edgeband]  FROM [tbl_BHMCategoryMaster] ' 
exec(@cmd)
```

I get this error and i have no clue what i am doing wrong

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Dime'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Dime'.

But again when i tried this

```
 exec('SELECT [category_id],[category_name],[Basic],[Dimension],[In_Out],[ProfileHand],[Glass],[Hinge],[Edgeband]  FROM [tbl_BHMCategoryMaster]')
```

it worked properly.

There may be many alternative to this but i want to know the problem in detail so that i don't face it next time. If anyone can put some light it will be of great help. Thanks :)

Comment: Your `nvarchar` needs to be bigger than `(50)`

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mistake  Laurence  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't declared `@cmd` to be long enough.  Try this:

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(max);
set @cmd = N'SELECT [category_id],[category_name],[Basic],[Dimension],[In_Out],[ProfileHand],[Glass],[Hinge],[Edgeband]  FROM [tbl_BHMCategoryMaster] ' ;
exec(@cmd);
```

Comment: that was so lame of me..Anyways thanks for pointing out the mistake Gordon :)